# Does iTunes play count gets increased while listening with iPod/iPhone/iPad?

Tags: itunes

If I have a song A with play count of 10, then I play the song once (1 time) on my computer, 3 times on my iPad, and 4 times with my iPhone; would the play count go to 18,next time I sync all my devices?

Comment: The question I've always wondered about but never bothered to ask...

Comment: Your welcome... Deep in my mind I think it's the case but I can't be sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

P.S.

This is one of those things you can check easily just by using and then syncing your device =)

Comment: Thank you! I could check easily, but I share an iPod with other people in my family...

Comment: Ah, got it. Now you know =)